# How is this method using a parameter that is never given a value?

Tags: javascript, methods, parameters

I came across the .every() method today and found this example code to explain how it works:

```
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function checkAdult(age) {
    return age >= 18;
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ages.every(checkAdult);
}
```

The result of `myFunction()` is `false`, and I understand what the method is doing (going through each value of the array and checking if the value is `>= 18`, but I don't understand how the `.every()` method is able to use the `age` parameter in its return statement without `age` being declared in the method call.

Does the method somehow automatically know that it should be referencing the index of the array it's looking at? That's the only explanation I can come up with, but I can't find any explanation of this online.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) explains this.  `every` calls the function `checkAdult` with the parameter given in `ages` - "every" single element in that array.

Comment: "that is never given a value" — It is given a value. Look at what `every` does.

Comment: it is called [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Comment: `ages.every(function (age) { return checkAdult(age); })` - makes more sense? It passes a function which takes one argument and returns a result (the result of `checkAdult(age)`). Well… `checkAdult` already is a function that takes one argument and returns a result, so just get rid of the superfluous anonymous function wrapper → `every(checkAdult)`.

Comment: I just realized I misspoke...my bad. What I meant to say was that I don't understand how `checkAdult()` is called within `.every()` without having some value assigned to its `age` parameter. I know that parameters are optional in JS, but since `checkAdult()` is using its parameter in the return statement I would think it would need to have a value passed to it when being used in the `.every()` method.

Comment: Do you understand what a *callback* function is? Do you understand how `ages.every(function (age) ...)` gets its `age` argument?

Comment: @deceze Correct, I don't understand how it gets the `age` argument. Which I guess also means that I don't understand callback functions lol.

Comment: @NickMartini basically like this: `Array.prototype.every = function(fn){
 for(var i = 0; i<this.length; ++i){
  if(i in this && !fn(this[i], i, this)) return false;
 }
 return true;
}` the `fn(this[i]`-part is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

> without age being declared in the method call.

It **is** declared in the method call. You simply aren't looking at the method call.

`checkAdult` is passed as an argument to `every`. The code inside `every` calls that function and passes it a value.